# How to make setters for List JAXB

Tags: java, list, maven, xsd, jaxb

I have some XSD files, I try to generate Java Class (Jaxb) with setters for attributes java.util.List.

I have this pom.xml :

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.13.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/here</schemaDirectory>
                    <generatePackage>ws</generatePackage>
                    <includeSchema>${basedir}/src/main/resources/file.xsd</includeSchema>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                            <version>0.10.0</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I added but this parameter is not recognized :

```
<arg>-Xcollection-setter-injector</arg>
```

Do you know how to do ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you miss the `configuration` parameter `extension`.

```
<extension>true</extension>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<configuration>
                    <extension>true</extension>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xsimplify</arg>
                        <arg>-Xcollection-setter-injector</arg>
                    </args>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                            <version>0.11.0</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </configuration>
```